# getters e setters não funcionam com HttpGet

Tags: c#, .net

Boa tarde pessoal, possuo o seguinte código:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ObterGridParceirosComPaginacao(PaginacaoVueTableViewModel filtro)
    {
        Resultado resultado = new Resultado();
        var viewModel = new PaginacaoVueTableRetornoViewModel();

        return Json(viewModel);
    }
```

Com a seguinte ViewModel:

```
public class PaginacaoVueTableViewModel
{

    private int page;
    private string orderBy;

    public int Page
    {
        get
        {
            return page;
        }
        set
        {
            page = value > 0 ? value - 1 : value;
        }
    }
    public string OrderBy
    {
        get
        {
            return orderBy;
        }
        set
        {
            orderBy = value == null ? string.Empty : value;
        }
    }
}
```

O corpo do método ObterGridParceirosComPaginacao ainda não está implementado, mas o meu problema está quando eu recebo a ViewModel como parâmetro, os setters não estão aplicando as regras que estão estabelecidas neles. Coloquei alguns breakpoints e percebi que em nenhum momento os getters e os setters são chamados, portanto não aplicam as regras. Alguém sabe oque pode ser?

Obs: A ViewModel vem com todos os valores corretos, enviados do Javascript, preciso apenas que esses valores passem pelas validações dos getters e setters.

Comment: setters não fazem alteração sem serem chamados

Comment: Mas não existe alguma maneira que eu consiga chama-los? Ou existe alguma maneira melhor de fazer isso que estou tentando fazer?

Comment: O problema é que o parâmetro ```filtros``` chega nulo? Se for isso, o problema deve ser mapeamento de JSON para classe C#. No ASP.Net Core, usando o json ```{
    "page":1,
    "orderBy":"teste"
}```funcionou, pois a regra de mapeamento é CamelCase para PascalCase. Se você quiser um JSON diferente desse, você pode usar o JsonProperty para explicitamente dizer ao .Net qual o nome Json da propriedade.

Comment: pra chamar o setter no seu caso é só colocar o nome da propriedade, e aí no momento em que ele setar ele vai fazer a sua lógica ali ex: filtro.OrderBy = null; //quando você fazer isso aqui ele vai preencher com ""

Comment: Então o parâmetro filtros, ele vem preenchido, porém ele não aplica as regras que estão nos setters, por exemplo, se eu enviar do Javascript o atributo Page com o valor 10, de acordo com a regra ele deveria virar 9, porém ele é mantido como 10, ou seja a regra não foi executada. E em nenhum momento ele para no breakpoint que coloco no setter.

Answer (score 0):

Não há problema algum com seus setters, o erro pode estar na forma como você está fazendo a requisição, veja a demonstração abaixo.

Porém, perceba que na atribuição da variável `teste` onde a `PaginacaoVueTableRetornoViewModel` instanciada, mas nenhum valor é atribuído para uma das propriedades... por razões, lógicas o set não é invocado...

E esse seria o comportamento apresentado na sua action `ObterGridParceirosComPaginacao` que recebe essa model sob o parâmetro `filtro`, você não o utiliza e logo abaixo envia para a `View` um objeto "vazio".

```
var viewModel = new PaginacaoVueTableRetornoViewModel();
return Json(viewModel);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]